# Confusion about the steps of a limit calculation.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am Having some trouble understanding the solution of a limit in a solution manual.

$\lim_{x\to 0}$ $\cfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\cos(bx)}$

=$\lim_{x\to 0}$ $\cfrac{2\sin^2(\cfrac{ax}{2})}{2\sin^2(\cfrac{bx}{2})}$

=$\cfrac   { \lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{\sin\cfrac{ax}{2}}{\cfrac{ax}{2}}\times\lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{\sin\cfrac{ax}{2}}{\cfrac{ax}{2}}\times a^2  }  {\lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{\sin\cfrac{bx}{2}}{\cfrac{bx}{2}}\times\lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{\sin\cfrac{bx}{2}}{\cfrac{bx}{2}}\times b^2} $

[If $x$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ , then $\cfrac{ax}{2}$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ , $\cfrac{bx}{2}$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ ]

=$\cfrac{1\cdot 1\cdot a^2}{1\cdot 1\cdot b^2}$

=$\cfrac{a^2}{b^2}$

Here, I am not understanding the third step and the fourth step. Can someone help me to find where is my flaw in understanding this?

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ tends to $1$ when $x$ tends to $0$ ?

Comment: Yes I know that.But i didn't quite understand how they derived the third step from second step.

Comment: Maybe try to understand how you could go *from* the third step *to* the second step.

Comment: Basically a multiplication by a factor of $\frac{1}{4a^2}$ followed by a factor of $a^2$ to cancel out the denominator.

Comment: What @TheSilverDoe implied is that you use the fact the the fundamental limit $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is defined and can be evaluated. The rest is just algebraic manipulation to use this limit.

Comment: Can you show me How to get the third step from the second step as a answer?

Comment: They divide both numerator and denominator by $x^2/8$, then divide and multiply both numerator and denominator by $a^2$ and $b^2$ respectively

Comment: I did this limit with lopitals rule and got the same answer.Is that valid?

Comment: @Prithubiswas It is valid, but if you don't understand the written proof, I would still advise you to spend some time on it, until you understand it :)

Comment: @Prithubiswas using l'Hospital implies you know how to evaluate the limit $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x \to 0$

Comment: Here is what I came to so far:This limit was done in the solution manual without lopitals rule because the derivatives chapter comes after the limits excercise .The problem is they skipped and tangled upa bunch of extra steps making it confusing(I dont know why they skipped 2 to 3 steps like this).Also "using l'Hospital implies you know how to evaluate the limit sinx/x when x→0 ,"That is true .I can ether use loptals rule or not use loptals rule,it is my choice.